# Как узнать все имена файлов в директории, а также их количество в си, в ОС Linux?

Tags: linux, c, файлы, файловая-система

Как узнать все имена файлов в директории, а также их количество в си, в ОС Linux?

Comment: Атомарно? Никак. Но можно приблизится с помощью всяких нотификаторов. Если неатомарно, то ниже примерное решение, хотя и не без проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 * This program displays the names of all files in the current directory.
 */

#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) {
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir(".");
  if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }
    closedir(d);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program/17683417)